# How to use named bindings with laravel's query builder?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'd like to do the following:

```
MyModel::where(MyModel::sql_distance_to(), ['lat' => '...', 'lng' => '...'])->get();
```

Where `sql_distance_to()` returns some complex sql expression. But from what I can see, query builder doesn't support named bindings. Is this true? Any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you mean using [Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#query-scopes)

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public function scopeSqlDistanceTo($query, $lat, $lon)
    {
        // Previously DB::raw(expr) was here.
        // No need since we're using whereRaw()
        $whereRaw = 'lat = ? AND lon = ?';

        return $query->whereRaw($whereRaw, [$lat, $lon]);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$latitude = 0.0;
$longitude = 180.0;
MyModel::sqlDistanceTo($latitude, $longitude)->get();
```

Comment: Good point. No need to wrap expression with `DB::raw`, though.

Comment: @x-yuri Ah, of course! :) You're right. Nothing big but worth changing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Use [Skysplit's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258061/52499), if possible.

Here's what I came up with. One additional complication is that laravel by default [disables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39258516/52499) `pdo`'s emulation mode. Which results in being unable to use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a statement.

```
$q = MyModel::whereRaw(MyModel::sql_distance_to() . ' < :dist');
run_query_with_params(MyModel::class, $q,
    array_merge(MyModel::sql_distance_to_params($lat, $lng), [
        'dist' => 10,
    ]));

class MyModel {
    static function sql_distance_to() {
        return 'ACOS(
            SIN(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(:lat1))
            + COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:lat2))
                * COS(RADIANS(:lng - lng))
        ) * 6371';
    }

    static function sql_distance_to_params($lat, $lng) {
        return [
            'lat1' => $lat,
            'lat2' => $lat,
            'lng' => $lng,
        ];
    }
}

function run_query_with_params($class, $q, $params)
{
    $r = \DB::select($q->toSql(), $params);
    return call_user_func([$class, 'hydrate'], $r);
}
```