# Laravel complains about query with duplicate named parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

When I do (in laravel):

```
<?php
\DB::select('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = :id || id = :id', [
    'id' => 1,
]);
```

It says:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = :id || id = :id)

But when I do (in pure php):

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=...', '...', '...');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = :id || id = :id');
$r = $stmt->execute([
    'id' => 1,
]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($row['id']);
}
```

It succeeds. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. Apparently, the query I ran when I encountered the issue was more meaningful.

**UPD** More or less real query:

```
SELECT id
FROM objects
WHERE ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(:lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:lng - lng))
) * 6371 < 10
```

Comment: Better use `OR` instead of `||` in your query

Comment: But why `id = :id` twice? connected with an `OR`?

Comment: Like I said, the query was a little bit involved, like `... ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(:lat)) + COS(RADIANS(lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:lat)) * COS(RADIANS(:lng - lng))) * 6371 ...`, you can see to `:lat` parameters here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see it all comes down to `mysql` being unable to deal with named parameters.

[`mysqli::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> This parameter can include one or more parameter markers in the SQL statement by embedding question mark (?) characters at the appropriate positions.

[`pdo::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php):

> You must include a unique parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute(). You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, unless emulation mode is on.

Laravel has emulation mode [disabled](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/42d9a58/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L24) [by default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/42d9a58/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php#L37). One can enable it in `config/database.php` by adding `'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE]` to connection settings. That way you will get the same result as in pure php. Not sure that's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve that using a CROSS JOIN with a "constant" derived table (subquery in FROM clause). Then I can reuse the parameters as many times as I want.

```sql
SELECT id
FROM objects o
CROSS JOIN (SELECT :lat as lat, :lng as lng) params
WHERE ACOS(
    SIN(RADIANS(o.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(params.lat))
    + COS(RADIANS(o.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(params.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(params.lng - o.lng))
) * 6371 < 10
```

Comment: Any performance drawbacks with the cross join?

Comment: @IjasAmeenudeen - Not in this case, since the "constant" table has only one row. I don't think you can measure any performance difference compared to if you would just repeat the values of lat and lng in the WHERE clause.