# How to bind paramater a sql query paramater in Laravel with out Raw select?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query,

```
$query = "SELECT id,name, user_birthday FROM `users` where DATE_FORMAT(user_birthday, '%m-%d') >=";
$query .=" DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') and DATE_FORMAT(user_birthday, '%m-%d')<=";
$query .=" DATE_FORMAT((NOW() + INTERVAL +14 DAY), '%m-%d') and id in (";
$query .=" (SELECT friend_id FROM user_friends where user_id = :userID";
$query .=" UNION ";
$query .=" SELECT friend_id FROM user_friends where user_id in (SELECT friend_id FROM user_friends where user_id = :userID)))";
$query .=" order by DATE_FORMAT(user_birthday, '%m-%d') ASC";

$res = DB::select($query, ['userID' => $userID]);
```

For some reason i can't bind the UserID paramter without using Raw select, i guess it's because the complexitivity and the hirarchy of the query...

Comment: Laraval's Query Builder supports [UNION](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#unions), which i suggest you to use instead of this code..

Comment: Thanks, Can you add an example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel complains about query with duplicate named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257070/laravel-complains-about-query-with-duplicate-named-parameters)

Comment: Just use `:userID1` and `:userID2` and bind `['userID1' => $userID, 'userID2' => $userID]`

Comment: this is not worthy of the `laravel` tag.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - what's the different from what i've done?

Comment: @Flame so help me and i'll close it :)

Comment: You have `:userID` twice. That doesn't work with non-emulated prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You have `:userID` twice. That doesn't work with non-emulated prepared statements.

*(answered by @Paul Spiegel in the comments)*

Comment: Thanks, i was under the inpression that it does... otherwise i would have pass the param directlly... do you know for a better way to scure params with sql query? does Laravel support some sort of PDO?

Comment: _The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks_ ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries)). But with your complex query using the Query Builder might not be possible.

Comment: Or it might be possible but very hard; a `UNION` example is shown in the documentation. If I were you I'd give it a try, and perhaps post a new question on how to convert your SQL to Query Builder.

Comment: @RoyBarOn The core Laravel [database connection  `DB::connection()`  uses `PDO`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#using-multiple-database-connections) aka abstraction layer, which is then passed to the QueryBuilder. The question I flagged as duplicate provides a solution to your specific issue, by enabling PDO emulation in your database configuration. [Laravel complains about query with duplicate named parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257070/laravel-complains-about-query-with-duplicate-named-parameters)